# Merge the result of groupby into the orginal dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe with 411165 rows:

```
    LastTime        Dur         SrcAddr     DstAddr    Proto Sport  Dport
0   03:20:18.581977 0.816447    10.0.0.1    10.0.0.4    udp 57532   tftp
1   03:20:32.313861 4.885413    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.4    udp 59977   tftp
2   03:20:37.366970 4.938308    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.4    udp 59977   tftp
3   03:20:42.420143 4.938177    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.4    udp 59977   tftp
4   03:20:47.473281 4.938372    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.4    udp 59977   http-alt
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
411161  22:28:29.841361 0.000000    231.127.193.147 10.0.0.4    udp 37335   tftp
411162  22:28:29.933401 0.000000    39.216.12.51    10.0.0.4    udp 36823   tftp
411163  22:28:29.997108 0.000000    153.183.248.241 10.0.0.4    udp 37336   tftp
411164  22:28:30.148128 0.000000    49.29.36.35 10.0.0.4    udp 36824   tftp
411165  22:28:30.229133 0.000000    62.248.30.126   10.0.0.4    udp 37337   tftp
```

I performed a groupby operation on the dataframe in batches of a 100:

```
grouper=dataset.groupby([(np.arange(len(dataset.index))//100),'DstAddr','Dport'])
ct_sv_dst=grouper['LastTime'].count()
```

The result of the groupby operation is:

```
DstAddr   Dport   
0     10.0.0.3  http-alt      2
      10.0.0.4  tftp         98
1     10.0.0.3  http-alt     33
      10.0.0.4  tftp         67
2     10.0.0.3  http-alt     34
                           ... 
4107  10.0.0.4  tftp        100
4108  10.0.0.4  tftp        100
4109  10.0.0.4  tftp        100
4110  10.0.0.4  tftp        100
4111  10.0.0.4  tftp         66
Name: LastTime, Length: 6252, dtype: int64
```

now I want to merge the result of the group by operation into the original dataframe, please can someone guide me on how I can achieve this.
The result I want is like this:

```
      LastTime      Dur         SrcAddr     DstAddr    Proto Sport  Dport gc
0   03:20:18.581977 0.816447    10.0.0.1    10.0.0.4    udp 57532   tftp  98
1   03:20:32.313861 4.885413    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.4    udp 59977   tftp  98
2   03:20:37.366970 4.938308    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.4    udp 59977   tftp  98
3   03:20:42.420143 4.938177    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.4    udp 59977   tftp  98
4   03:20:47.473281 4.938372    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.4    tcp 59977  http-alt 2
.
.
100  02:20          3.232       10.0.0.1    10.0.0.3    tcp 3234  http-alt 33 
101  02:20          3.232       10.0.0.1    10.0.0.4    udp 3234  tftp    67
```

Comment: Do you want to merge the count results into the original data frame?

Comment: yes, similar to the last dataframe with column called gc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do the job.

```
dataset['gc'] = grouper['LastTime'].transform('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to ensure that the 2 dataframes have same columns, before concatenating. So far the result of the groupby operation are missing a few columns. Fix this by passing more column grouping rules to `ct_sv_dst = grouper.agg({'LastTime':'count', 'proto':lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0], MORE AGG RULES HERE})`

Then concatenate the original dataframe and the result of `groupby()agg()` with pd.DataFrame.concat(). more details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)